# How many independent cycles of length 3 in a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a complete graph $K_n$ with $n\ge 3$ vertices. Now how many "independent" 3-cycles are in this graph? By independent, I mean that the minimal number of 3-cycles to generate any cycle in $K_n$. For example, $K_3$ has 1 independent 3-cycle and $K_4$ has 3 independent 3-cycles. I think the answer is
$$
\left( {n-1}\atop 2 \right)
$$
However, I'm not quite sure how to obtain this result. It only came from a hunch.

Comment: By `generate', do you mean you can take symmetric differences of the edge-sets of the 3-cycles to get any other cycle you like?

Answer (score 1):

The formula suggests a solution. Let $u$ be a fixed vertex and consider the triangles of the form $uvw$ for $v,w \in V$. This specifies $\binom{n-1}{2}$ triangles. They are independent since $vw$ is not contained in $uv'w'$ for $\{v',w'\} \neq \{v,w\}$. They are a generating set since any triangle $abc$ is the symmetric difference of the triangles $uab,ubc$ and $uca$.